# how to replace the special character with escape character

Tags: perl

```
my $c=  'ODD_`!"£$%^&*(){}][@@;:/?.>,<|\'
```

I want to replace all of them into as special character

how achiveve this in faster way ..

```
my $c=  'ODD_\`\!\"\£\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\{\}\]\[\@\,\;\:\/\?\.\>\,\<\|\\'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `quotemeta`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings; use strict;

my $c = 'ODD_`!"£$%^&*(){}][@@;:/?.>,<|\\';

print quotemeta($c), "\n";
```

Note that your definition of `$c` would not compile as you have to escape `\` even in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

While I think that Sinan's answer is correct for what I am assuming you need (based on your list of characters to escape), for completeness I will add the module [`URI::Escape`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3aEscape) which escapes the metacharacters in HTML text. It does seem that it has some facility to specify the unsafe characters though, so perhaps it could help you too.